# Django template tags- run once and use that value

Tags: django, templatetags

I have a loop in a template:

```
 {% for item in replies %}
....
      {% include '...show_content.html' with poall=item.limited_content_chunks %}
```

In the model I have a function/property which computes something I want to compute once. 
Problem is this gets called every time there is a page refresh.
Whats the most effective way of solving this problem?

I could create dictionary of pre-computed chunks for each reply in replies and send it as a context object, or I could...

```
def limited_content_chunks(self, percentage=None):
    if not self.content and self.po_file:
     # do crazy stuff which could might lead to a nuclear war
    .... 
    return ' '.join(chunks)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use django's template caching here.

You can call create a new html template and include your heavy duty content template like this.

Your current template looks like this now and

```
{% for item in replies %}
....
      {% include 'cached_content.html' with item=item %}

{% endfor %}
```

And the `cached_content.html`

```
{% load cache %}
{% cache 300 item.id %}
    {% include '...show_content.html' with poall=item.limited_content_chunks %}
{% endcache %}
```

The template caching is a disk based cache AFAIK which means if you have 100's of servers at first will execute your nuclear code to setup the cache. There should be implementation centralised caching for templates as well.

Secondly if you have request specific code in your template it will break because the key for your template cache is `item.id` only.